# На хостинге находит эту стр, но не находит стр на панели в чем проблема?

Tags: php, html, база-данных, mysqli

Нажимая на "авторизацию Админа" должен перекидывать на "админ панель" но эту стр не находит почему то...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот что выдает...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На хостинге то же самое проделываю и все работает(вар 1)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
На хостинге то же самое проделываю и все работает(вар 2)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот и все находит почему так? я в первые с этим сталкиваюсь(может на панели какой то другой путь указывать надо, если да то какой?)

путь хостинг
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

путь на панели
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Если нужно будет файлы или скрины докинуть(скажите кину)

link.php

```
    <?php
session_start();



// $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "f0440307_regauth", "2511", "f0440307_regauth") or die("Error!!!");
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "f0440307_regauth") or die("Error!!!");

        $login = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['login']));
        $password=htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['password']));
  $name=htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['name']));
  $email=htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['email']));
  $dublepassword=htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['dublepassword']));

        // $password = md5(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['password'])));

    if(isset($_POST['do-registr'])){

  if(!empty($login) and !empty($password) and !empty($name)){
$check_query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE login = '$login' ");
$check_array = mysqli_fetch_array($check_query);
if($check_array['COUNT(id)'] == 0){

if(preg_match("~^[a-zа-яё ]+$~ui",$name)) {

if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
 
if(preg_match("/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{6,25}$/",$password)) {

if($dublepassword==$password){

if(isset($_POST['do-registr'])){
    $img_type = substr($_FILES['img_upload']['type'], 0, 5);
    $img_size = 2*1024*1024;
    if(!empty($_FILES['img_upload']['tmp_name']) and $img_type === 'image' and $_FILES['img_upload']['size'] <= $img_size){ 
    $img = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['img_upload']['tmp_name']));

    }

mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO users (login,password,name,email,img) VALUES ('$login', '$password','$name','$email','$img') ");//можно короче   $connection->query("INSERT INTO users (img) VALUES ('$img')");
echo "Регистрация прошла успешно";
}
else {
    echo "Аву обязательно";
}
}else {
    echo "Пароли не совподают";
}
}else {
    echo "Пароль должен содержать не менее 6 символов английской раскладки, верхнего и нижнего регистра";
}

}else {
    echo "E-mail адрес '$email' указан неверно";
}

}else{
        echo "Имя Фамилия Отчество указано не верно вот пример:Данил Исламов Вадимович";
}
}else{
        echo "Логин занят";
}
}
}


    if(isset($_POST['do-auth'])){
        $query_auth = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = '$login' AND password = '$password' ");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($query_auth) == 1){
            $row_auth = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_auth);
            $_SESSION['user'] = array($row_auth['id'], $row_auth['login'], $row_auth['password']);
            header("location: authreg/guest");
        }
    }
    if(isset($_POST['do-auth-admin'])){
        $query_auth = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = 'admin' AND password = 'Wsr2018' ");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($query_auth) == 1){
            $row_auth = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_auth);
            $_SESSION['user'] = array($row_auth['id'], $row_auth['login'], $row_auth['password']);
            header("location: authreg/admin");
        }
    }
?>
<div><a href="link.php?link=registr">Регистрация</a> | <a href="link.php?link=auth">Авторизация</a></div>
    <?php
    $link = $_GET['link'];
    if($link === 'registr') require_once("authreg/reg.php");
    elseif($link === 'auth') require_once("authreg/auth.php");
?>
```

admin/index.php

```
    <?php
session_start();
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "f0440307_regauth", "2511", "f0440307_regauth") or die("Error!!!");

if(empty($_SESSION['user']))
    header("location: ../../");

if($_GET['link'] === 'logout'){
    unset($_SESSION['user']);
    session_destroy();
    header("location: ../../");
}
  $len=($_POST['nameselect']);
   $name_z=htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['name_z']));
    $op=htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['op']));
        if(isset($_POST['do-len'])){
mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO users (login,password,name,email,img,len,name_z,op) VALUES ('$login', '$password','$name','$email','$img','$len','$name_z','$op') ");  
 }

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Панель управления</title>
<style type="text/css">
  body{
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<h3>Создание заявки</h3>
<form  method="post">

  <label>Название<br><input type="text" name="name_z"></label><br>
  Описание<br><textarea name="op" cols="21"></textarea>

<p><select size="3" name="nameselect" multiple>
    <option value="Врач1">Врач1</option>
    <option value="Врач2">Врач2</option>
    <option value="Врач3">Врач3</option>
   </select></p>
   <p><input type="submit" name="do-len"value="Отправить"></p>
   </form>
<body>
    <h3>Просмотр своей заяки</h3>
  <?php

  $sql = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `name_z` = '$name_z'");
$result = $sql->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo '<p>'.'Название:'."<br>".$row['name_z'].'</p>';
}
$sql = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `op` = '$op'");
$result = $sql->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo '<p>'.'Описание:'."<br>".$row['op'].'</p>';
}


$sql = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `len` = '$len'");
$result = $sql->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo '<p>'.$row['len'].'</p>';
}


?>
<h3>Удаление заявки</h3>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['do-delete'])){
  
 
$query = "delete from users where id=22";
$result = $connection->query($query);
}
$query = "select * from users";
$result = $connection->query($query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

echo "id ".$row ['id']."<br>";
}

?>
<p><input type="submit" name="do-delete" value="Удалить"></p>
<div><?php echo "Привет, ".$_SESSION['user'][1]; ?> | <a href="index.php?link=logout">Выйти</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: auth.php]

Comment: У вас на локальной машине URL localhost:81/**public_html**/link.php, а потом перекидывает на localhost:81/link.php (без public_html в пути) - наверное, в этом причина.

Answer (score 0):

```
($link === 'auth') require_once("authreg/auth.php")
```

А где сам authreg/auth.php?

А ваши всякие `WHERE login = '$login'` - это прямая дорога к [SQL Injection](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0).

Comment: Я добавил скрин который вы просили, надеюсь он поможет вам